# How to place a Kotlin extension in a class file?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

Maybe this question is answered in the [official doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html), but I'm not seeing it...

In Swift we are used to write something like

```
class Jazz {
...
}

extension Jazz {
    func swing() {
    ...
    }
}
```

and place that whole code snippet in a single file, say `Jazz.swift`.

We don't seem to be able to do the corresponding thing in Kotlin? I'm always finding my selfe writing e.g. one `Jazz.kt` and one `JazzExtensions.kt`, which simply isn't always the clearest way of structuring the code.

Any input on this is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't the swift code equivalent to putting `class Jazz` and `fun Jazz.swing() {}` within the same Kotlin file?

Comment: Why would you use an extension and don't just add the function as an ordinary one inside the class?

Comment: @BakaWaii Yes, apparently it is :). I swear that I've tried that before with no luck :P.

Comment: You may also put what you've tried in the question next time and show what is the error you get. So that, you may find your answer while you are typing your question :)

Comment: @s1m0nw1 It has mainly to do with code clarity. You "always" wan't to separate chunks of functions/code that has to do with a specific task. Remember that this can be multiple extensions on the same class. 
A small gain can also be if you have a set of private functions - then you can make the extension private and that is more clear than having lots of individually private methods in the class.. 
And at least in Swift, with Structs, you have a thing with default constructors that you avoid with extensions. Not sure if the same goes for Kotlin.

Comment: @BakaWaii That's a perfectly valid comment :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the extension function inside or outside the class:

Outside:

```
class Jazz { ... }

fun Jazz.bar() {
    println("hello")
}
```

Inside (in the `companion object`):

```
import YOUR_PACKAGE.Jazz.Companion.bar

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Jazz().bar()
}

class Jazz {
    companion object {
        fun Jazz.bar() {
            println("hello")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still missing an `extension` keyword though. Maybe in the bright Kotlin-future.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very different from **Swift**:

```
class Jazz {
    val a = "Jazz"
}

fun Jazz.swing() = a

////////////

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    print(Jazz().swing()) // >>> Jazz
}
```

Comment: Hahaha, I could have sworn I've tried that... Damn, this got embarrassing quickly :). Thanks for the answer, but I've accepted @guenhter's since that was more detailed.

Comment: And he was first as well :)